# Проблема с циклом в Python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет.
Решаю задачки из ЕГЭ по Питону, попалась вот такая:

Ниже на пяти языках программирования записан алгоритм. Получив на вход число x, этот алгоритм печатает два числа a и b. Укажите наименьшее из таких чисел x, при вводе которых алгоритм печатает сначала 2, а потом 12.

И дан код программы:

```
x = int(input())
a=0; b=1
while x > 0:
    if x%2 > 0:
        a += x%8
    else:
        b = b * (x%8)
    x = x//8
print(a, b)
```

Пытаюсь решить перебором:

```
a = 0
b = 1
for x in range(1, 10001):
    while x > 0:
        if x%2 > 0:
            a += x%8
        else:
            b = b * (x%8)
    if (a == 2 and b == 12):
            print(x)
    x = x//8
```

В итоге программа как будто не отрабатывает, но VS Code никаких ошибок не выдает. Есть подозрение на бесконечный цикл, но не могу понять, что не так с кодом. Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Comment: да, бесконечный цикл. И если есть такое подозрение, то нужно его проверить, а не гадать. Добавь в цикл while после последней строчки print(x), только на один уровень с if

Comment: опечатка вы икс не меняете и цикл бесконечный. x = x//8 у вас после принтов, а нужно выше на пару строк.

Comment: код программы правильно отформатирован? Непохоже, что он вообще когда-нибудь выведет 2 и 12.

Comment: @Эникейщик если вы говорите про исходный код программы (который дан в задании), то там похоже что а вообще никогда не будет равна 2 (пардон, остаток же может быть нулем)
добавила скрин из задания в текст вопроса, на всякий случай

Comment: а равно 2 когда х равно 9. После этого а начинает резко расти.

Comment: @Эникейщик можете, пожалуйста, написать правильный код? я и так и эдак меняю и все равно не получается

Comment: ну какой тут может быть правильный код. При х=9 b не равно 12, а других случаев, когда а равно 2, вроде бы, не наблюдается. Думаю, что в задании ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

исправлены опечатки, код работает

```
for i in range(1, 10001):
    a=0
    b=1
    x=i
    while x > 0:
        if x%2 > 0:
            a += x%8
        else:
            b = b * (x%8)
        x = x//8
    if (a == 2 and b == 12):
            print(a, b, i)
```

ответы

```
2 12 598
2 12 626
2 12 654
2 12 689
2 12 906
2 12 913
2 12 1102
2 12 1137
2 12 1417
2 12 3146
2 12 3153
2 12 3209
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Оказалось все так просто, я почему-то даже и не подумала о том, что возможно самое задание некорректное

Comment: про задание я ничего не говорил, лишь подправил ваши опечатки. перенёс икс в цикл while и А Б  в цикл for. поменял местами 3 строчки. ну и принт подправил чтобы было видно 2 и 12.

Comment: Блин,  а у меня что-то совсем не получилось, хотя вроде то же самое делал. Видимо где-то затупил конкретно 